# ASP.NET: returning list of objects from Web Service method

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, serialization, business-logic-layer

I wonder how to return a list of objects instead of a list of strings?

Returning a list of strings works, but when I replace everything by an object it fails..

Here's my Web Service

```
[WebMethod]
 public List<OpProduct> SearchProduct(string name) {
   BLProduct blProduct = new BLProduct();
   List<OpProduct> result = byproduct.SearchProducts(name);

   return result;
}
```

And here's my Business Logic Layer

```
public List<OpProduct> SearchProducts(string name)
{
  List<OpProduct> result = (from item in db.OpProducts where item.Name.StartsWith(name) select item).ToList<OpProduct>();

  return result;
}
```

And here's my error message (sorry, could not translate this)

> System.InvalidOperationException: Er is een fout opgetreden bij het
>   genereren van het XML-document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Er is een kringverwijzing aangetroffen tijdens het toepassen van
>   serialisatie op een object van het type OpProduct.    bij
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteStartElement(String
>   name, String ns, Object o, Boolean writePrefixed,
>   XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns)    bij
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write9_OpProduct(String
>   n, String ns, OpProduct o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
>   bij
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write5_OpGeheugen(String
>   n, String ns, OpGeheugen o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
>   bij
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write9_OpProduct(String
>   n, String ns, OpProduct o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
>   bij
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write10_ArrayOfOpProduct(Object
>   o)    bij
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ListOfOpProductSerializer.Serialize(Object
>   objectToSerialize, XmlSerializationWriter writer)    bij
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter,
>   Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle,
>   String id)    --- Einde van intern uitzonderingsstackpad ---    bij
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter,
>   Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle,
>   String id)    bij
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter
>   textWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)    bij
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.XmlReturnWriter.Write(HttpResponse
>   response, Stream outputStream, Object returnValue)    bij
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.WriteReturns(Object[]
>   returnValues, Stream outputStream)    bij
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.WriteReturns(Object[]
>   returnValues)    bij
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your xml serialization fails. You can (and should) test it separately from the actual web method. My bet - either **OpProduct** is not serializable, or some fields contain invalid characters.

Answer (score 1):

By default only the system primitive types and arrays of these primitive types (like int, float, double, string) can be used as a return value.

If you want to use your own classes as parameters you have to define them as complex types by using XML definition. Here is a MSDN link about this
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480498.aspx